# Finding unimodular matrix analytically, not combinatorially

Tags: matrices, determinant

I'm playing with 3x3 matrices composed of natural numbers $\{1, 2, 3,  4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ and their determinants.

Magic squares happen to have their determinant $360$ or $-360$, e.g.

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
8 & 1 & 6 \\ 
3 & 5 & 7 \\ 
4 & 9 & 2
\end{vmatrix}
= -360
$$

The "combinatorically first" matrix happens to have determinant 0

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
7 & 8 & 9
\end{vmatrix}
= 0
$$

Now I would like to find a matrix, or possibly all matrices of this kind, that are unimodular, i.e. having determinant 1.

I could find them with brute force, combinatorially, and find all (45) resulting matrices (see appendix A).
However, can that this problem be solved "analytically", by calculation, and how? (Preferably matrix operations).

To make this problem somewhat more narrow, say I prefer matrices whose rows are permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{4,5,6\}$ and $\{7,8,9\}$, respectively.

This can translate to more generic problem: Find a $n{\times}n$ matrix whose elements are ($n^2$ long list of $a_{1,1}$ to $a_{n,n}$ follows), whose determinant is $d$. "Analytically".
(or to more narow problem: ... whose rows are permutations of ($n$ $n$-long lists follow) ... )

APPENDIX A

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
8 & 5 & 9 \\
6 & 4 & 7
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 \\
6 & 5 & 9 \\
4 & 8 & 7
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 1 & 5 \\
4 & 9 & 8 \\
3 & 7 & 6
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 5 & 1 \\
3 & 6 & 7 \\
4 & 8 & 9
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
5 & 1 & 2 \\
6 & 7 & 3 \\
8 & 9 & 4
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
7 & 1 & 2 \\
4 & 6 & 3 \\
8 & 9 & 5
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
7 & 1 & 2 \\
8 & 9 & 6 \\
5 & 4 & 3
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 6 & 3 \\
4 & 8 & 9 \\
2 & 7 & 5
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
6 & 1 & 3 \\
7 & 2 & 5 \\
8 & 4 & 9
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 6 & 4 \\
3 & 5 & 9 \\
2 & 8 & 7
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
7 & 1 & 4 \\
8 & 3 & 9 \\
5 & 2 & 6
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
7 & 4 & 1 \\
5 & 6 & 2 \\
8 & 9 & 3
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 9 & 6 \\
7 & 2 & 4 \\
8 & 3 & 5
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
8 & 1 & 7 \\
3 & 9 & 2 \\
5 & 6 & 4
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
8 & 1 & 7 \\
6 & 4 & 5 \\
3 & 9 & 2
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 9 & 2 \\
8 & 1 & 7 \\
6 & 4 & 5
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 9 & 2 \\
5 & 6 & 4 \\
8 & 1 & 7
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
7 & 2 & 4 \\
8 & 3 & 5 \\
1 & 9 & 6
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
5 & 2 & 6 \\
7 & 1 & 4 \\
8 & 3 & 9
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
5 & 6 & 2 \\
8 & 9 & 3 \\
7 & 4 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 7 & 5 \\
1 & 6 & 3 \\
4 & 8 & 9
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
7 & 2 & 5 \\
8 & 4 & 9 \\
6 & 1 & 3
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 8 & 7 \\
1 & 6 & 4 \\
3 & 5 & 9
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
5 & 4 & 3 \\
7 & 1 & 2 \\
8 & 9 & 6
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
4 & 6 & 3 \\
8 & 9 & 5 \\
7 & 1 & 2
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
8 & 3 & 5 \\
1 & 9 & 6 \\
7 & 2 & 4
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 5 & 9 \\
2 & 8 & 7 \\
1 & 6 & 4
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 6 & 7 \\
4 & 8 & 9 \\
2 & 5 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 7 & 6 \\
2 & 1 & 5 \\
4 & 9 & 8
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
6 & 7 & 3 \\
8 & 9 & 4 \\
5 & 1 & 2
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
8 & 3 & 9 \\
5 & 2 & 6 \\
7 & 1 & 4
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
8 & 9 & 3 \\
7 & 4 & 1 \\
5 & 6 & 2
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
5 & 6 & 4 \\
8 & 1 & 7 \\
3 & 9 & 2
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
6 & 4 & 5 \\
3 & 9 & 2 \\
8 & 1 & 7
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
6 & 4 & 7 \\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
8 & 5 & 9
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
4 & 8 & 7 \\
1 & 3 & 2 \\
6 & 5 & 9
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
4 & 8 & 9 \\
2 & 5 & 1 \\
3 & 6 & 7
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
4 & 8 & 9 \\
2 & 7 & 5 \\
1 & 6 & 3
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
4 & 9 & 8 \\
3 & 7 & 6 \\
2 & 1 & 5
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
8 & 4 & 9 \\
6 & 1 & 3 \\
7 & 2 & 5
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
8 & 9 & 4 \\
5 & 1 & 2 \\
6 & 7 & 3
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
6 & 5 & 9 \\
4 & 8 & 7 \\
1 & 3 & 2
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
8 & 5 & 9 \\
6 & 4 & 7 \\
1 & 2 & 3
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
8 & 9 & 5 \\
7 & 1 & 2 \\
4 & 6 & 3
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
8 & 9 & 6 \\
5 & 4 & 3 \\
7 & 1 & 2
\end{vmatrix}
= 1
$$

Note that no matrix meets the narrowed condition.

Comment: permutation of columns change only the sign of the determinant, so for your narrow problem you can try all 36 combinations by hand or computer